# Unable to share http request between two subscribers

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an application that gets random jokes every 10 seconds. I'm using interval operator from rxjs for countdown and after 10 seconds i make a http request to get a random joke. The issue is i'm displaying jokes twice in my template using async pipe. I know that doing that will create two new subscriptions and make http request twice. To handle that i tried using shareReplay or publish + refCount , so that only one http request is made. But it calls getRandomJoke service function twice. How to fix this issue.

Code and Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xvtsrw

random-joke.component.html

```
<div class="joke-title">{{joke | async}}</div>
<div class="joke-title">{{joke | async}}</div>
<div class="footer">Next Joke in : {{countdown | async}}</div>
```

random-joke.component.ts

```
export class RandomJokesComponent implements OnInit {
  joke: Observable<any>;
  restartTimer = new Subject();
  restartInterval = new Subject();
  intervalForJokes: Observable<any>;
  countdown: any;
  countDownTill = 10;
  constructor(private fetchService: FetchUtilService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startTimer();
    this.getJokesInInterval();
  }
  getJokesInInterval() {
    this.restartInterval.next();
    let intervalForJokes = interval(10000);
    this.joke = intervalForJokes.pipe(
      tap(()=> console.log('getting interval')),
      takeUntil(this.restartInterval),
      publish(),
      refCount(),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.fetchService.getRandomJoke().pipe(
          tap(() => this.startTimer()))
      )
    );
  }
  startTimer() {
    this.restartTimer.next();
    this.countdown = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.restartTimer),
      map(i => this.countDownTill - i)
    );
  }
}
```

fetch-service

```
getRandomJoke(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('getting');
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
      tap(result => console.log(result)),
      // shareReplay(),
      publish(),
      refCount(),
      map((result: any) => result && result.value.joke)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is overcomplicated.
Use `shareReplay` and start joke fetching immediately by using `startWith(0)`.
`FetchUtilService.getRandomJoke` can be simplified just to http request logic + error handling.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.startTimer();

    this.joke = interval(10000).pipe(
      startWith(0),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.fetchService.getRandomJoke().pipe(tap(() => this.startTimer()))
      ),
      shareReplay(),
    );
  }
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class FetchUtilService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getRandomJoke(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('getRandomJoke invocation');
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiUrl)
      .pipe(map((result: any) => result && result.value.joke));
  }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpugke

Bonus: restart timer on mouse click

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
        debounceTime(400),
        startWith(null), // init timer
    );

    this.timer$ = click$.pipe(
        switchMap(() => interval(1000)), // kills interval on click and starts new one
    );

    const readyToFetch$ = this.timer$.pipe(
        map((seconds) => seconds > 0 && seconds % 10 === 0), // fetch every 10 seconds, skip 0 to avoid joke's fetching on timer restart
    );

    this.joke$ = readyToFetch$.pipe(
        startWith(true), // initial fetch
        filter((readyToFetch) => readyToFetch),
        switchMap(() => this.fetchService.getRandomJoke()),
        shareReplay(),
    );
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uak1sx

Comment: I prefer this answer! I updated the code to be further optimized by making it purely functional/reactive without relying on external state properties. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-paffdm?file=src/app/random-jokes/random-jokes.component.ts

Comment: I tend to prefer to move as much logic as possible to the service layer away from Components. In this case this would mean to move the logic which is in `ngOnInit` to the `FetchUtilService`. One advantage would be in testability. It is mush easier to test the logic of a service than testing the logic of a Component.

Comment: @digclo I also wanted to restart the interval if the user clicks anywhere on the screen that is why i also had the startTimer function. How do i make it work now? I have updated my stackblitz code with your logic. It's working but i feel it might be handled in a better way.

Comment: @Picci It would be better to keep service logic as generic as possible since it is shared by many components with varying requirements. In this use case there may be another component that needs a joke without any time constraint. Rather than declaring both observables (w/ time and w/o time) in the service, it is far easier to have each component define the observable they need. This way they can both subscribe to the sole source observable in the service without concern that the source data has been mutated.

Comment: Nothing prevents to have a **sole source observable** shared among different other observables, via `share` or `shareReplay`, which are defined as public by the service. Again, I think it is easier to test than Components, but definitely this is not science and it depends also on personal taste.

Comment: @alia I added sample with implementation of the timer restarting on mouse click without additional subjects. I also provided demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same response of an http call, you better think to use `Subject`s.

The mechanism can be the following.

First you create a service which exposes a method, for intance `callRemoteService`, to fire the http call and an Observable, for instance `httpResp`, that will emit the response. `httpResp$` is obtained tranforming a private Subject, for instance `_resp$`  into an Observable using the `asObservable()` method of Subject.

Then, when the Obvervable linked to the http call emits, you make the internal Subject `_resp$` emit as well.

More than one client can subscribe to the public `httpResp$` Observable and will receive the same notification when the http call returns.

The code could look like this

```
private _resp$ = new Subject<any>();
public httpResp$ = this._resp$.asObservable();

public callRemoteService() {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
     tap({
        next: (data) => this._resp$.next(data),
        error: (err) => this._resp$.error(err)
     })
  ).subscribe()
}
```

You may find more inspiration in [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/reactive-programming-with-react-and-rxjs-88d2789e408a). It talks about React, but the mechanism illustrated there can be applied to Angular too.